# trying to get the circles next to the y axis labels in bar chart d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I'm trying to remove the y axis from my bar chart however I want to leave the y axis label and grid lines in bar graph I want to add cicle right to the labels(low,medium, high , critical) which have different colors  as well

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.grid path {
      stroke-width: 0;
}
</style>

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
          
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right-100,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom-100;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right+100)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom+100)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",`translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// Parse the Data


    const defs = svg.append('defs');

    const bgGradient = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'bg-gradient')
      .attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90)');
    bgGradient
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#74E6FF')
      .attr('offset', '0%');
    bgGradient
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#FDFDFF')
      .attr('offset', '100%');
      
    const bgGradient1 = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'bg-gradient1')
      .attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90)');
    bgGradient1
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#1574FF')
      .attr('offset', '0%');
    bgGradient1
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#FDFDFF')
      .attr('offset', '100%');
      
      
    const bgGradient2 = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'bg-gradient2')
      .attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90)');
    bgGradient2
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#0B4291')
      .attr('offset', '0%');
    bgGradient2
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#FDFDFF')
      .attr('offset', '100%');

   var data = [
    {
      "Risk": "Security Risk",
      "Impact": 2,
      "Likelihood": 4,
      "Rating": 6,
    },
    {
      "Risk": "XYZ Risk",
      "Impact": 8,
      "Likelihood": 6,
      "Rating": 4,
    },
    {
      "Risk": "Two Risk",
      "Impact": 2,
      "Likelihood": 4,
      "Rating": 6,
    }

  
  ]

    
    
  
  
  const groups=["Security Risk","XYZ Risk","Two Risk"]
  const subgroups=["Impact","Likelihood","Rating"]


    // Add X axis
    var x = d3.scaleBand().domain(groups).range([0, width/2]).padding(0.2);
    svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 8]).range([height, 0]);
    function draw_yAxis_gridlines() {
          return d3.axisLeft(y)
            .tickValues(3);
        }

    svg.append("g")
    
    .call(
        d3
            .axisLeft(y).tickSize(0)
            
            // .tickValues(["Low", "Medium", "High", "Critical"])
            .ticks(3)
            .tickFormat((d, i) => ["","Low", "Medium", "High", "Critical"][i])
    )
    ;
    svg.append("g")         
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .call(make_y_gridlines()
          .tickSize(-width)
          .tickFormat("")
      )

    // gridlines in y axis function
    function make_y_gridlines() {       
        return d3.axisLeft(y)
            .ticks(3)
            .tickFormat((d, i) => ["Low", "Medium", "High", "Critical"][i])
    }
    

    // Another scale for subgroup position?
    var xSubgroup = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .domain(subgroups)
        .range([0, 91])
        .padding(0.05);


    // color palette = one color per subgroup
    var color = d3
        .scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(subgroups)
        .range(["#74E6FF", "#1574FF", "#0B4290"]);

    const rx=12;
    const ry=12;

  // Show the bars
  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    // Enter in data = loop group per group
    .data(data)
    
    .join("g")
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${x(d.Risk)}, 0)`)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return subgroups.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .join("rect")
      .attr("x", d => xSubgroup(d.key))
      .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
      
      .attr("width", 30)
      .attr("height", d => height - y(d.value))
      .attr("fill", function (d) { 
      console.log("d",d["key"]);
      if(d["key"]=="Impact") {
        return "url(#bg-gradient)"
      
      }
      else if(d["key"]=="Likelihood") {
        return "url(#bg-gradient1)"
      
      }
      else if(d["key"]=="Rating") {
        return "url(#bg-gradient2)"
      
      }
      })
      .attr("d", (item) => {
        console.log(item);
        return `
        M xSubgroup(item.key) ,y(item.value) + ry
        a rx ,ry 0 0 1 rx,-ry
        h xSubgroup.bandwidth() - 2 * rx
        a rx, ry 0 0 1 rx,ry
        v height - y(item.value) - ry
        h -xSubgroup.bandwidth()Z
      `;
      });


  var color_domain = [50, 150, 350]
  var ext_color_domain = [0, 50, 150 ]
  var legend_labels = ["Impact", "Likelihood", "Ratings"]   
  
var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legend")
.data(ext_color_domain)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "legend");

var ls_w = 80, ls_h = 20;

legend.append("rect")
.attr("x", function(d, i){ return width/2 - (i*ls_w) - ls_w - 4*i;})
.attr("y", 310)
.attr("width", ls_w)
.attr("height", ls_h)
.style("fill", function (d,i) { 
      console.log("d",d["key"]);
      if(i==0) {
        return "url(#bg-gradient)"
      
      }
      else if(i==1) {
        return "url(#bg-gradient1)"
      
      }
      else if(i==2) {
        return "url(#bg-gradient2)"
      
      }
      })
.style("opacity", 0.8);

legend.append("text")
.attr("x", function(d, i){ return width/2 - (i*ls_w) - ls_w - 4;})
.attr("y", 300)
.text(function(d, i){ return legend_labels[i]; });

</script>
```

This is my current output
[image]

Expected output
[image]

any help or guidance will be a great help .
And Thanks in advance . comment below for any unclearity in question

Edit 1

The below edit doesn't solve any of the problem but I have removed the unnecessary code which I thought wasntr much help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.grid path {
      stroke-width: 0;
}
</style>

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
          
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right-100,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom-100;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right+100)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom+100)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",`translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// Parse the Data


    const defs = svg.append('defs');

    const bgGradient = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'bg-gradient')
      .attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90)');
    bgGradient
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#74E6FF')
      .attr('offset', '0%');
    bgGradient
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#FDFDFF')
      .attr('offset', '100%');
      
    const bgGradient1 = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'bg-gradient1')
      .attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90)');
    bgGradient1
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#1574FF')
      .attr('offset', '0%');
    bgGradient1
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#FDFDFF')
      .attr('offset', '100%');
      
      
    const bgGradient2 = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'bg-gradient2')
      .attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90)');
    bgGradient2
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#0B4291')
      .attr('offset', '0%');
    bgGradient2
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#FDFDFF')
      .attr('offset', '100%');

   var data = [
    {
      "Risk": "Security Risk",
      "Impact": "Low",
      "Likelihood": "Medium",
      "Rating": "High",
    },
    {
      "Risk": "XYZ Risk",
      "Impact": "Critical",
      "Likelihood": "Low",
      "Rating": "High",
    },
    {
      "Risk": "Two Risk",
      "Impact": "Medium",
      "Likelihood": "Critical",
      "Rating": "High",
    }

  
  ]

    
    
  
  
  const groups=["Security Risk","XYZ Risk","Two Risk"]
  const subgroups=["Impact","Likelihood","Rating"]


    // Add X axis
    var x = d3.scaleBand().domain(groups).range([0, width/2]).padding(0.2);
    svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scalePoint()
            .domain(["","Low", "Medium", "High", "Critical"]).range([height, 0]);
    function draw_yAxis_gridlines() {
          return d3.axisLeft(y)
            .tickValues(3);
        }

    svg.append("g")
    
    .call(
        d3
            .axisLeft(y).tickSize(0)
            
    )
    ;
    svg.append("g")         
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .call(make_y_gridlines()
          .tickSize(-width)
          .tickFormat("")
      )

    // gridlines in y axis function
    function make_y_gridlines() {       
        return d3.axisLeft(y)
            .ticks(3)
    }
    

    // Another scale for subgroup position?
    var xSubgroup = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .domain(subgroups)
        .range([0, 91])
        .padding(0.05);


    // color palette = one color per subgroup
    var color = d3
        .scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(subgroups)
        .range(["#74E6FF", "#1574FF", "#0B4290"]);

    const rx=12;
    const ry=12;

  // Show the bars
  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    // Enter in data = loop group per group
    .data(data)
    
    .join("g")
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${x(d.Risk)}, 0)`)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return subgroups.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .join("rect")
      .attr("x", d => xSubgroup(d.key))
      .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
      
      .attr("width", 30)
      .attr("height", d => height - y(d.value))
      .attr("fill", function (d) { 
      console.log("d",d["key"]);
      if(d["key"]=="Impact") {
        return "url(#bg-gradient)"
      
      }
      else if(d["key"]=="Likelihood") {
        return "url(#bg-gradient1)"
      
      }
      else if(d["key"]=="Rating") {
        return "url(#bg-gradient2)"
      
      }
      })
      .attr("d", (item) => {
        console.log(item);
        return `
        M xSubgroup(item.key) ,y(item.value) + ry
        a rx ,ry 0 0 1 rx,-ry
        h xSubgroup.bandwidth() - 2 * rx
        a rx, ry 0 0 1 rx,ry
        v height - y(item.value) - ry
        h -xSubgroup.bandwidth()Z
      `;
      });


  var color_domain = [50, 150, 350]
  var ext_color_domain = [0, 50, 150 ]
  var legend_labels = ["Impact", "Likelihood", "Ratings"]   
  
var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legend")
.data(ext_color_domain)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "legend");

var ls_w = 80, ls_h = 20;

legend.append("rect")
.attr("x", function(d, i){ return width/2 - (i*ls_w) - ls_w - 4*i;})
.attr("y", 310)
.attr("width", ls_w)
.attr("height", ls_h)
.style("fill", function (d,i) { 
      console.log("d",d["key"]);
      if(i==0) {
        return "url(#bg-gradient)"
      
      }
      else if(i==1) {
        return "url(#bg-gradient1)"
      
      }
      else if(i==2) {
        return "url(#bg-gradient2)"
      
      }
      })
.style("opacity", 0.8);

legend.append("text")
.attr("x", function(d, i){ return width/2 - (i*ls_w) - ls_w - 4;})
.attr("y", 300)
.text(function(d, i){ return legend_labels[i]; });

</script>
```

Edit 3
I was able to remove the y axis successfully but problem of getting the circles next to the labels("low", "high" ,"medium", "critical") still exist.
below is the edited code that I did

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style>
.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.grid path {
      stroke-width: 0;
}
</style>

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
          
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right-100,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom-100;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right+100)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom+100)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",`translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// Parse the Data


    const defs = svg.append('defs');

    const bgGradient = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'bg-gradient')
      .attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90)');
    bgGradient
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#74E6FF')
      .attr('offset', '0%');
    bgGradient
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#FDFDFF')
      .attr('offset', '100%');
      
    const bgGradient1 = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'bg-gradient1')
      .attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90)');
    bgGradient1
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#1574FF')
      .attr('offset', '0%');
    bgGradient1
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#FDFDFF')
      .attr('offset', '100%');
      
      
    const bgGradient2 = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'bg-gradient2')
      .attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90)');
    bgGradient2
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#0B4291')
      .attr('offset', '0%');
    bgGradient2
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#FDFDFF')
      .attr('offset', '100%');

   var data = [
    {
      "Risk": "Security Risk",
      "Impact": "Low",
      "Likelihood": "Medium",
      "Rating": "High",
    },
    {
      "Risk": "XYZ Risk",
      "Impact": "Critical",
      "Likelihood": "Low",
      "Rating": "High",
    },
    {
      "Risk": "Two Risk",
      "Impact": "Medium",
      "Likelihood": "Critical",
      "Rating": "High",
    }

  
  ]

    
    
  
  
  const groups=["Security Risk","XYZ Risk","Two Risk"]
  const subgroups=["Impact","Likelihood","Rating"]


    // Add X axis
    var x = d3.scaleBand()
                    .domain(groups) // This is what is written on the Axis: from 0 to 100
                    .range([0, width/2])  // This is where the axis is placed: from 100 px to 800px
                    .padding(0.2);  // Goes between 0 and 1. Default is 0
    svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scalePoint()
            .domain(["","Low", "Medium", "High", "Critical"]).range([height, 0]);
    function draw_yAxis_gridlines() {
          return d3.axisLeft(y)
            .tickValues(3);
        }

    svg.append("g")
    
    .call(
        d3
            .axisLeft(y).tickSize(0)
            
    )
    .select(".domain").remove()
    ;
    svg.append("g")         
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .call(make_y_gridlines()
          .tickSize(-width)
          .tickFormat("")
      )

    // gridlines in y axis function
    function make_y_gridlines() {       
        return d3.axisLeft(y)
            .ticks(3)
    }
    

    // Another scale for subgroup position?
    var xSubgroup = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .domain(subgroups)
        .range([0, 91])
        .padding(0.05);


    // color palette = one color per subgroup
    var color = d3
        .scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(subgroups)
        .range(["#74E6FF", "#1574FF", "#0B4290"]);

    const rx=12;
    const ry=12;

  // Show the bars
  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    // Enter in data = loop group per group
    .data(data)
    
    .join("g")
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${x(d.Risk)}, 0)`)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return subgroups.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .join("rect")
      .attr("x", d => xSubgroup(d.key))
      .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
      
      .attr("width", 30)
      .attr("height", d => height - y(d.value))
      .attr("fill", function (d) { 
      console.log("d",d["key"]);
      if(d["key"]=="Impact") {
        return "url(#bg-gradient)"
      
      }
      else if(d["key"]=="Likelihood") {
        return "url(#bg-gradient1)"
      
      }
      else if(d["key"]=="Rating") {
        return "url(#bg-gradient2)"
      
      }
      })
      .attr("d", (item) => {
        console.log(item);
        return `
        M xSubgroup(item.key) ,y(item.value) + ry
        a rx ,ry 0 0 1 rx,-ry
        h xSubgroup.bandwidth() - 2 * rx
        a rx, ry 0 0 1 rx,ry
        v height - y(item.value) - ry
        h -xSubgroup.bandwidth()Z
      `;
      });


  var color_domain = [50, 150, 350]
  var ext_color_domain = [0, 50, 150 ]
  var legend_labels = ["Impact", "Likelihood", "Ratings"]   
  
var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legend")
.data(ext_color_domain)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "legend");

var ls_w = 80, ls_h = 20;

legend.append("rect")
.attr("x", function(d, i){ return width/2 - (i*ls_w) - ls_w - 4*i;})
.attr("y", 310)
.attr("width", ls_w)
.attr("height", ls_h)
.style("fill", function (d,i) { 
      console.log("d",d["key"]);
      if(i==0) {
        return "url(#bg-gradient)"
      
      }
      else if(i==1) {
        return "url(#bg-gradient1)"
      
      }
      else if(i==2) {
        return "url(#bg-gradient2)"
      
      }
      })
.style("opacity", 0.8);

legend.append("text")
.attr("x", function(d, i){ return width/2 - (i*ls_w) - ls_w - 4;})
.attr("y", 300)
.text(function(d, i){ return legend_labels[i]; });

</script>
```

Current Output :
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example with color bullets:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 20, left: 50},
    width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right-100,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom-100;
    
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green'];

// append the svg object to the body of the page
const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right+100)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom+100)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",`translate(${margin.left},${margin.top})`);

// Parse the Data


    const defs = svg.append('defs');

    const bgGradient = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'bg-gradient')
      .attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90)');
    bgGradient
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#74E6FF')
      .attr('offset', '0%');
    bgGradient
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#FDFDFF')
      .attr('offset', '100%');
      
    const bgGradient1 = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'bg-gradient1')
      .attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90)');
    bgGradient1
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#1574FF')
      .attr('offset', '0%');
    bgGradient1
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#FDFDFF')
      .attr('offset', '100%');
      
      
    const bgGradient2 = defs
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', 'bg-gradient2')
      .attr('gradientTransform', 'rotate(90)');
    bgGradient2
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#0B4291')
      .attr('offset', '0%');
    bgGradient2
      .append('stop')
      .attr('stop-color', '#FDFDFF')
      .attr('offset', '100%');

   var data = [
    {
      "Risk": "Security Risk",
      "Impact": 2,
      "Likelihood": 4,
      "Rating": 6,
    },
    {
      "Risk": "XYZ Risk",
      "Impact": 8,
      "Likelihood": 6,
      "Rating": 4,
    },
    {
      "Risk": "Two Risk",
      "Impact": 2,
      "Likelihood": 4,
      "Rating": 6,
    }

  
  ]

    
    
  
  
  const groups=["Security Risk","XYZ Risk","Two Risk"]
  const subgroups=["Impact","Likelihood","Rating"]


    // Add X axis
    var x = d3.scaleBand().domain(groups).range([0, width/2]).padding(0.2);
    svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(0));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 8]).range([height, 0]);
    function draw_yAxis_gridlines() {
          return d3.axisLeft(y)
            .tickValues(3);
        }

    
    svg.append("g")         
      .attr("class", "grid")
      .call(make_y_gridlines()
          .tickSize(-width)
          .tickFormat("")
      )

    // gridlines in y axis function
    function make_y_gridlines() {       
        return d3.axisLeft(y)
            .ticks(3)
            .tickFormat((d, i) => ["Low", "Medium", "High", "Critical"][i])
    }
    

    // Another scale for subgroup position?
    var xSubgroup = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .domain(subgroups)
        .range([0, 91])
        .padding(0.05);


    // color palette = one color per subgroup
    var color = d3
        .scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(subgroups)
        .range(["#74E6FF", "#1574FF", "#0B4290"]);

    const rx=12;
    const ry=12;

  // Show the bars
  svg.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    // Enter in data = loop group per group
    .data(data)
    
    .join("g")
      .attr("transform", d => `translate(${x(d.Risk)}, 0)`)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return subgroups.map(function(key) { return {key: key, value: d[key]}; }); })
    .join("rect")
      .attr("x", d => xSubgroup(d.key))
      .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
      
      .attr("width", 30)
      .attr("height", d => height - y(d.value))
      .attr("fill", function (d) { 
      console.log("d",d["key"]);
      if(d["key"]=="Impact") {
        return "url(#bg-gradient)"
      
      }
      else if(d["key"]=="Likelihood") {
        return "url(#bg-gradient1)"
      
      }
      else if(d["key"]=="Rating") {
        return "url(#bg-gradient2)"
      
      }
      })
      .attr("d", (item) => {
        console.log(item);
        return `
        M xSubgroup(item.key) ,y(item.value) + ry
        a rx ,ry 0 0 1 rx,-ry
        h xSubgroup.bandwidth() - 2 * rx
        a rx, ry 0 0 1 rx,ry
        v height - y(item.value) - ry
        h -xSubgroup.bandwidth()Z
      `;
      });


  var color_domain = [50, 150, 350]
  var ext_color_domain = [0, 50, 150 ]
  var legend_labels = ["Impact", "Likelihood", "Ratings"]   
  
var legend = svg.selectAll("g.legend")
.data(ext_color_domain)
.enter().append("g")
.attr("class", "legend");

var ls_w = 80, ls_h = 20;

legend.append("rect")
.attr("x", function(d, i){ return width/2 - (i*ls_w) - ls_w - 4*i;})
.attr("y", 310)
.attr("width", ls_w)
.attr("height", ls_h)
.style("fill", function (d,i) { 
      console.log("d",d["key"]);
      if(i==0) {
        return "url(#bg-gradient)"
      
      }
      else if(i==1) {
        return "url(#bg-gradient1)"
      
      }
      else if(i==2) {
        return "url(#bg-gradient2)"
      
      }
      })
.style("opacity", 0.8);

legend.append("text")
.attr("x", function(d, i){ return width/2 - (i*ls_w) - ls_w - 4;})
.attr("y", 300)
.text(function(d, i){ return legend_labels[i]; });

    const yAxis = svg.append("g")
    
    .call(
        d3
            .axisLeft(y).tickSize(0)
            
            .ticks(3)
            .tickFormat((d, i) => ["","Low", "Medium", "High", "Critical"][i])
    );
    
    const ticks = yAxis.selectAll('.tick');
    
    ticks.filter((d, i) => i > 0)
        .append('circle')
      .attr('cx', 0)
      .attr('cy', 0)
      .attr('r', 5)
      .style('fill', (_, i) => colors[3 - i])

ticks.select('text').attr('dx', -5);
```

```css
.grid .tick {
    stroke: lightgrey;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
.grid path {
      stroke-width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems to be creating the y axis (not the grid lines) which I don't want

Comment: `yAxis` is not created twice but rather used by name to modify ticks. Just inspect all the elements before and after the change and see that nothing has been added except of the bullets

Comment: it didnt but it did help me out a bit. that's why I just upvoted your answer